# What Key Usage values are required to support Code Signing?

Tags: certificates, code-signing, key-usage

I have a .pfx that I want to use to sign a Clickonce app. However, on trying to do so, Visual Studio gives me `"The selected certificate is not valid for code signing."` When I go to certmgr.msc and check the certificate, it states "Code signing" under Enhanced Key Usage (non-critical) and "Key Encipherment" under Key Usage (critical). Is the certificate missing a Key Usage value in order for it to code sign?

Comment: This looks like a Visual Studio-specific question?

Comment: So based on the given key usage, it SHOULD be able to code sign? I also try to sign with mage, and it gives me same error

Comment: I just checked a valid code signing certificate and I *think* only digital signature (key usage) and code signing are required. Does your certificate include *digital signature*?

Comment: @SEJPM, Do you know if that valid code signing certificate works for ClickOnce manifests? I ask this because my certificate works for signing .exe's and .dll's but not ClickOnce, for whatever reason

Comment: @Chara I just looked at an EV signed binary (KeePass) and reported the key usages here. (Hint: Windows usually allows you to inspect certificates)

Comment: The project designer allows for the creation of the test certificate. You can use this certificate to compare it with yours. Generally windows has different requirements for the user code and kernel code. Check the signature of your cert.